# VB.NET: Password encryption

Tags: vb.net, password-protection, password-encryption

What's the simplest way to upgrade a VB.NET site to using encrypted passwords?  Are there easy to use encryption algorithms built in to System.UI?

My site is using plain text password storage, and it will soon be going to a public server at godaddy from a private one on the local network.  I'm going to have to start adding in encryption algorithms to all the password parsing functions, and it would be nice if I could just set a SALT key in the web.config file and Encrypt(password) or something like that.

Comment: You can use a built-in class for hashing (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.aspx), and SHA1 or MD5 shall be adequate if used with salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in `System.UI` but definitely in `System.Security.Cryptography`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

There are definitely standard "good practices" you'll want to follow.  No point in re-inventing the wheel, especially when it comes to password storage.  There are [a lot of resources](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20password%20hashing) for that, and they're better at it than I am :)

Comment: Yeah, that looks pretty useful.  All I need to do is create 3 functions, `getSalt(user_id)`, `encrypt(salted_string)` and `decrypt(encr_str, salt)`.  It should be simple enough.  All of our DB query strings are already parameterized and secure anyway, but I need to start looking at encrypting the sensitive client data in addition to the password encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a salt for each user and store it in the database.  Then hash the users incoming plain text password, add the salt to it and hash it again.  For extra security, hash the password at the client before posting back to your server.  Once you have the posted hash, you can add the salt to it and hash it again then store that value as the users password.  This basically ensures that no one, even if they have access to your database can easily get to the users passwords.

This is the simplest way and all that is required is a reference to the cryptography libraries.  You can get as fancy as you want with your algorithm.  I've just provided a loose example of something that could be easily done in just a few minutes.

Comment: How do I hash at the client if this particular site uses no JavaScript (part of spec)?  Not to mention, JS hashing is completely transparent...

Comment: It's just a suggestion so the password isn't sent over the wire in plain text.  Nothing you ever do on the client side can be trusted which is why no matter what, you still want to hash at the server level using a salt.

Comment: Ok gotcha.  I guess I was thinking that it wouldn't really matter if I hash client side, because if it's intercepted, that hashed version could be sent to the server as is, and would still be functional.